# Renaming first child elements only

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to select and rename the first child element with an XSL. But it's not really the first child, it's more like the first node of the first child.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Root><Story>
 <CL>
  <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
  <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
 </BK> 
 <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
 </CL>
 <CL>
  <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
  <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
 </BK> 
 <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
 </CL>
</Story></Root>
```

I need the first `<name>` element after `<CL>` to be renamed, such as `<name1>` while leaving the other `<name>` elements as is:

```
<Root><Story>
 <CL>
  <BK>
   <name1>...</name1>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
  <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
 </BK> 
 <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
 </CL>
 <CL>
  <BK>
   <name1>...</name1>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
  <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
 </BK> 
 <BK>
   <name>...</name>
   <Address>...</Address>
  </BK> 
 </CL>
</Story></Root>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is about how to select the correct elements (not about how to replace them once you've found them), the following XPath expression selects the first `<name>` element in the first child of each `<CL>` element:

```
/Root/Story/CL/*[1]/name[1]
```

Note how, under `<CL>`, an arbitrary element is selected (`*`). This selection is restricted to the first such element in its parent `<CL>` element by `[1]`.

**Update:** Embedded into an XSLT, the element could then be renamed with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root/Story/CL/*[1]/name[1]">
    <name1><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/></name1>
</xsl:template>
```

**Update 2:** Restricted selection to the first `<name>` element.

Comment: I am looking to rename that element. Do I use a CHOOSE statement to do this with a WHEN and OTHERWISE option? Or is there a better way?

Comment: @JimMaivald: I have updated my answer with an example for an XSLT template that renames the `<name>` elements. I am not sure where you want to use an `<xsl:choose>` element.

Comment: This is wrong as it will choose all the name elements of the first child of CL, not the first name under CL.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin: Thanks for pointing that out. Changed the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your comment, No you should not use WHEN/OTHERWISE. Overriding templates are the way to go.

The following XSLT 1.0 style-sheet is a simple interpretation of your rule "I need the first  element after  to be renamed, such as  while leaving the other  elements as is", without assuming any particular structure in the input document ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name[(preceding::name | ancestor::CL)[last()]/self::CL]">
 <name1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </name1>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Note

If you can use XSLT 2.0 or make certain guarantees about the structure of the input document, there will be simpler solutions. Update your question if either of these conditions are true.

Comment: This is the correct structure for the stylesheet but I think the match pattern of the second template rule can be simplified to `match="CL/BK[1]/name"`, at least for this example data.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a complete and short solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="BK[1]/name">
  <name1>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </name1>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Root><Story>
     <CL>
      <BK>
       <name>...</name>
       <Address>...</Address>
      </BK>
      <BK>
       <name>...</name>
       <Address>...</Address>
     </BK>
     <BK>
       <name>...</name>
       <Address>...</Address>
      </BK>
     </CL>
     <CL>
      <BK>
       <name>...</name>
       <Address>...</Address>
      </BK>
      <BK>
       <name>...</name>
       <Address>...</Address>
     </BK>
     <BK>
       <name>...</name>
       <Address>...</Address>
      </BK>
     </CL>
</Story></Root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Root>
   <Story>
      <CL>
         <BK>
            <name1>...</name1>
            <Address>...</Address>
         </BK>
         <BK>
            <name>...</name>
            <Address>...</Address>
         </BK>
         <BK>
            <name>...</name>
            <Address>...</Address>
         </BK>
      </CL>
      <CL>
         <BK>
            <name1>...</name1>
            <Address>...</Address>
         </BK>
         <BK>
            <name>...</name>
            <Address>...</Address>
         </BK>
         <BK>
            <name>...</name>
            <Address>...</Address>
         </BK>
      </CL>
   </Story>
</Root>
```

**Explanation**:

What actually is wanted is to rename the `name` child of the first `BK` element of any element (in this case just `CL`) that has `BK` children.

1. The **[identity rule](http://web.archive.org/web/20081229160200/http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every matched node (for which it is selected for execution) "as-is".
2. The identity template is overridden by a single template matching any `name` element that is a child of a `BK` element that is the first child of its parent. Here a `name1` element is generated and its attributes and body are copied unchanged by just applying templates (because they are matched and processed by the only other template -- the identity rule).